# Appium implicit wait doesn't work on hybrid app. Finding elements timeout without waiting

Tags: android, selenium, appium

Currently im having problems with Appium driver not waiting for an element on a hybrid app. It times out without waiting. Heres the code snippet. Im switching to the webview. clicking on the I have an account button and trying to send keys to the login box.

```
File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/src/testdata/");
File app = new File(appDir, "CordovaApp-debug.apk");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Motox");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.testing.Testing");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "CordovaApp");
driver=new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

@Test
public void ChangingLanguage() throws InterruptedException {

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
          String nr =   driver.getContextHandles().toString();
    if (nr.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
            driver.context("WEBVIEW_com.testing.Testing");
        break;
    }
    else
    {Thread.sleep(5000);}}
 PageObjects.WelcomeView.HaveanAccount(driver).click();
  Login.EmailBox(driver).sendKeys("madis@testing.com");
```

Heres the error message:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
>     (Session info: webview=)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 296 milliseconds

Comment: did you try explicit wait?

Comment: I tried explicit wait also. I got the same thing. It times out without waiting.

Comment: Please share your code by which you are trying to find that element.

Comment: I'm trying to find them with a cssSelector.  Heres the login box
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#LoginView[nav-view='active'] > ion-content > div.scroll > form > div.list.list-inset > label:nth-child(2) > input"));
Heres the haveanaccount: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#WelcomeView[nav-view='active'] > ion-content > div > div > button"));

The thing is. When i use thread.sleep(2000) for example. It finds the next element, as soon as i remove it. The test times out without waiting at all.